# Nginx Reverse proxy translate domain to ip

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm new with nginx, but i'm trying to build a reverse proxy that could do something like this:

Whenever a request arrives to a domain name like this in my nginx reverse proxy server:
http://dn.55-32.mydomain.name/path/file.cfg

Parse the 55-32 and forward the request to an internal ip.
http://10.10.55.32/path/file.cfg

The 55-32 represent that las octects XX.XX.55.32 to the forwarded server.
Is there a way to build such a behavior?

Comment: Shoud be possible with the "map" module: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: Seems that with map module i can capture the initial http request, and transform it to a static value.... i need something more flexible... using variables... in my example the part "55-32" could be any combination of two numbers.... i need to parse this part and use it as a variable then in the proxy_pass directive like:
proxy_pass http://10.10.55.32/path/file.cfg.

Comment: This screams for regex. With a combinatino on variable declarations, regex & map its should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i made it wokr with this configuration:

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;

        server_name ~^dn\.(?<octet1>.+)-(?<octet2>.+)\.mydomain\.com$;

        location / {
                set $var http://10.10.$octet1.$octet2;
                proxy_pass $var;
        }
}
```

Maybe this could be helpful for someone...

Ricardo